# How to make MS SQL with AWS Lambda on Windows?

Tags: python, sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pymssql

I want to make MS SQL connect with AWS Lambda function on Windows.

I can't follow AWS example document.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

I installed pip and virtualenv.

How to create a python deployment package?(lastest line)

> aws environment
>
> ec2 : windows server 2016(free tier)
>
> rds : mssql-express(free tier)

Comment: Are you asking how to create a ZIP file on Windows (where the ZIP file will contain your Python Lambda function and any Python packages you need)?

Comment: i don't know to attach pymssql.py. it's aws error
"Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pymssql'"

Comment: The documentation explains how to install modules to the root of your project folder (using pip install -t <folder>) and then you zip the contents of your project folder, giving you a deployment package. Did you do that? What is in your ZIP file?